British Sci-Fi Pre-1980, aliens use mind control on humans to steal germ weapon and turn against humans
I am trying to find the name of the book.
The main character is a writer who had some nightmares and found they are a part of aliens' mind controls.  He is able to break away and see how others got influenced.  He discovers that the aliens try to get some human into a weapon lab to steal germ weapons (Germ No. 214) to turn against humans.  If succeeds, all humans will be wiped out.  He tried to ask for help.  However, his wife, doctors, and government officials don't believe him.  He decides to steal the germ weapon back since he "saw" how it was stolen in the dreams.
Unfortunately, he mistook the thief.  The actual villain was the manager of the lab.  At the end, he was imprisoned in the lab and the manager has released the germs and the humans will be all killed within 7 days.
The MC's name sounds like Niven (?) and his wife's name is probably Sally (?)

Makes me think of Eric Frank Russell, but I can't find a specific story by him that fits.

Yes, the style is similar to EF Russell: one person against mind-controlling aliens.  However, none of his novels fits.
